# How to separate 2 values considering the first char as the separator with regex in java

Tags: regex

I have this string

```
key 123 . _kb=value=value
```

I want to create a regex to separate them in

```
(key) key 123 . _kb
(value) value=value
```

Note, my separator is `=`, I need to find the First `=`, it'll be my separator.

I tried this

```
(.+)\=(.+)
```

Comment: Use `([^=]+)=(.+)`

Comment: In Java, you may just use `split("=", 2)`.

Comment: @anubhava that works! Thanks, please answer to be accepted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a *negated character class* to make sure to match before `=` using this regex:

```
([^=]+)=(.+)
```

`[^=]+` will match 1 or more of any character that is not `=`.